# 1 presumably not equal to 1

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I got a surprise today and I couldn't find the appropriate part of the specification to find out whether this was to be expected or not. My money is on that [there's nothing wrong with the universe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx) but what are the rules that make this expression evaluate to false

```
(function(){ return this;}).call(1) === 1
```

Comment: add "use strict" to fix it. strict doesnt coerce _this_ to objects.

Comment: @dandavis thanks. I'm trying to find the part of the spec that makes it so

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what are the rules that make this expression evaluate to false

In "loose" mode the value of `this` is always coerced to an object. Values of type Object are not (strict) equal to values of type Number (or any other type for that matter):

```
new Number(1) === 1 // false
```

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3):

> **Entering Function Code**
>
> 1. If the function code is [strict code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1), set the [ThisBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to *thisArg*.
> 2. Else if *thisArg* is **null** or **undefined**, set the [ThisBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to the global object.
> 3. Else if [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*thisArg*) is not Object, set the [ThisBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to ToObject(*thisArg*).
>      ...

Comment: I am not sure why I feel that the [Note in `Function.prototype.call` section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) contradicts it.

Comment: Not necessarily. It just means that `.call` itself doesn't perform the conversion.

Comment: Hmmm, yup. That is how I chose to understand it :-)

Comment: It also says that it passes the values to `[[Call]]`. `[[Call]]` in turn invokes he algorithm quoted here. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1

Comment: Yup, I understood that part. But if someone just looks at the `Function.prototype.call` section, then it would be totally misleading I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The primitive 1 is converted to an *Number object* when it is set to *this* in *.call* because *this* is in javascript always an object.

And *[Number: 1]* is not strictly (===) the same as the primitive *1*.

But when using the non-strict equality operator (==) the *Number object* is converted to a primitive for comparison.

Comment: this can be a primitive (I learned that due to this question `(function(){ "use strict"; return this === 1;}).call(1)` will return true

Comment: @Rune FS Okay, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

depending of `'strict mode';`

```
in strict mode: true (type is number)
without strict mode: false (type is object)
```

Comment: what part of the spec makes it so?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the result of that function:

```
(function(){ return this;}).call(1)
```

You can see that the result is Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 1} so the result is an object not a primitive type. Since you are using three equals you are requesting that the type is the same:

```
(function(){ return this;}).call(1) === 1 // => FALSE

(function(){ return this;}).call(1) == 1  // => TRUE
```

This is not the strangest thing about javascript belive me ;-)

Comment: Yes that I'm aware of but I was looking for the rule that makes it so (which is only the case if it's not strict mode)

Answer (score 0):

`(function(){ return this;}).call(1)` returns an Object of type `Number`, according to FF developper console:

[image]

Whilst `1` is of a primitive type.